# Getting an Incorrect Syntax Error in CosmosDB When Using BETWEEN Statement For ISO 8601 Formatted DateTime

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

When I tried to execute the following query in CosmosDB I got the error `Syntax error, incorrect syntax near 'BETWEEN'`.

```
SELECT TOP 5 * FROM c
WHERE c.ApplicationName = "SampleApp" 
AND c.TimeStamp BETWEEN "20200902T095000Z" AND "20200902T095100Z"
```

I've seen in other articles that I should convert the date/time to an ISO 8601 string but still no luck. Please note that our `TimeStamp` field is stored as a string using the following format: `"2020-09-02T09:50:00.000"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got this error `Syntax error, incorrect syntax near 'BETWEEN'` is due to you didn't add parentheses.

Since your `TimeStamp` format is `"2020-09-02T09:50:00.000"`, you can try this SQL:

```
SELECT TOP 5 * FROM c
WHERE c.ApplicationName = "SampleApp"
AND (c.TimeStamp BETWEEN "2020-09-02T09:50:00.000" AND "2020-09-02T09:51:00.000")
```

It can work fine for me:

[image]